# Firebase: Users not registering

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble creating a Firebase user. I'm registering users through an HTML email and password form, although users aren't registering. No errors are showing on my console, so I don't think it's a problem with the school computer. Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>register</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="form">
        <div id="error"></div>
        <form onsubmit="registerUser();">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" id="password"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"><br>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
        function registerUser() {
            try {
                var config = {
                    databaseURL: 'https://apcs-4bfaa.firebaseapp.com/',
                    apiKey: 'AIzaSyD56uqnAm5xcfVttSD5NPEQHwn22ojWMhg'
                };
                firebase.initializeApp(config);

                // new 3.0 SDK method!
                var ref = firebase.database().ref();

                function registerUser() {
                    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
                    firebase.auth().createNewUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createNewUserWithEmailAndPassword is async. Make sure you return false and do not redirect your page until the promise returned is resolved.